# Removing Html tag from Java Hashmap value with efficient way

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, coding-efficiency

Removing Html tag from Java Hashmap value with efficient way

```
main(String str[]){
 HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("A", "Apple");
hm.put("B", "<b>Ball</b>");
hm.put("C", "Cat");
hm.put("D", "Dog");
hm.put("E", "<h1>Elephant</h1>");
}



 // we have to remove only html tags which have like B = <b>Ball</b> so the B = Ball
   // and E = <h1>Elephant</h1> should be E =Elephant
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("A", "Apple");
        hm.put("B", "<b>Ball</b>");
        hm.put("C", "Cat");
        hm.put("D", "Dog");
        hm.put("E", "<h1>Elephant</h1>");
        
        Map<String, String> newHm = hm.entrySet().
        stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")));
        
        
        System.out.println(newHm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is method [`Map::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which accepts a function replacing the values.

In this case the HTML tags may be removed from values using regular expressions and method `String::replaceAll`:

```java
hm.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.replaceAll("(\\<\\w+\\>)(.*)(\\</\\w+\\>)", "$2"));

System.out.println(hm);
```

Output showing that `Apple` and `Elephant` values are cleared from the HTML tags:

```
{A=Apple, B=Ball, C=Cat, D=Dog, E=Elephant}
```

Regular expression: `"(\\<\\w+\\>)(.*)(\\</\\w+\\>)"` looks for a sequence containing opening `(\\<\\w+\\>)` and closing `(\\</\\w+\\>)` tags and any text between them `(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        final Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("A", "Apple");
        hm.put("B", "<b>Ball</b>");
        hm.put("C", "Cat");
        hm.put("D", "Dog");
        hm.put("E", "<h1>Elephant</h1>");

        hm.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(entry -> entry.setValue(entry.getValue().replaceAll("</.*>", "").replaceAll("<.*>", "")));
        assertEquals("Ball", hm.get("B"));
        assertEquals("Elephant", hm.get("E"));
    }
```

Be sure to replace the ending tag first.

This will work with multiple tags as well (i.e. `<hi><b>Elephant</b></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. The two easiest would be to use:

1. Regex - match html tags and remove them from code

```java
private static String removeHtmlTags(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
}
```

2. Use external library like Jsoup to parse String into HTML tag and print content. The cons is that you have to add it to your `pom.xml`.

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
private static String removeHtmlTagsUsingParser(String input) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(input);
    return document.text();
}
```